# ¿Cómo generar un archivo .xls o .xlsx desde c# sin mensajes de advertencia?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

He encontrado en [diferentes](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) [fuentes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/export-gridview-to-excel/) algunos ejemplos para exportar la información contenida en un control [GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305359/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server/20095381#20095381) *(ASP.NET)* o en un [DataTable](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-to-excel-from-data-table-in-asp-net1) a un archivo .xls o .xlsx (Excel) desde C#.

En otra fuente, he [encontrado](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net) el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fuente: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt"></param>
public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, String nombreDelArchivo)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
        dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgGrid.DataBind();
        // Get the HTML for the control.
        dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreDelArchivo + "");
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

*Al ejecutar la funcionalidad anterior, obtengo el archivo Excel:*

[image: Resultado del archivo Excel a partir de un DataTable.]

Pero antes de ver el contenido del archivo Excel, aparece la siguiente advertencia:

[image: Mensaje de advertencia al abrir archivo Excel generado desde C#.]

*Después de presionar el botón **Sí** de la alerta anterior*; el archivo se muestra correctamente.

Para eliminar la alerta anterior, he intentado:

- Cambiar la extensión del archivo a generar (.xls, .xlx, .xlsx).
- Usar el Content-Type `application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
- `application/vnd.ms-excel`
- `application/xlsx`
- `application/xls`

Según la [fuente](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312023608/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx); es una característica de seguridad; pero me preguntaba si existe otra manera de generar un archivo Excel desde C#, teniendo como base la información almacenada en un `GridView` o en un `DataTable` que *en lo posible* no genere este tipo de mensajes.

Comment: Tal vez debes añadio:
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
. . .
_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siempre que exportes un html y lo quieras ver como excel vas a tener ese mensaje.

Deberías usar librerías basadas en openxml como ser

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

para que se genere el excel de forma correcta y lo envies en el Response

Si analizas los ejemplo veras que puedes exportar directo un dataset a excel

[Adding DataTable as Worksheet](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation)

Genera el excel con esta librería y lo envias en el Response, veras que este mensaje no debería aparecer cuando visualizas el documento.

Answer (score 6):

Con **Excel** solemos trabajar con dos formatos de archivos el nuevo formato (`XLSX`) que comenzó con `Excel 2007` y está basado en `XML` y el formato antiguo (`XLS`) que está en binario (tienes mas información sobre los formatos en [este](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-formats-that-are-supported-in-Excel-a28ae1d3-6d19-4180-9209-5a950d51b719#bmexcelformats) enlace)

Cualquiera de las librerías [ClosedXML](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/316934) y [EPPlus](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/316934) son válidas para trabajar con archivos `XLSX` pero no funcionan con archivos en formato antiguo `XLS`.

Para trabajar con archivos en formato antiguo (`XLS`), mi opción favorita es usando ADO.NET porque permite usar el archivo Excel como si fuese una base de datos.

Esta forma de trabajar es muy adecuada cuando tienes trabajar con bastantes datos. También tiene sus restricciones porque solo trabajas con los datos por lo que no se pueden establecer formatos, colores, anchos, ...

En [este artículo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/316934) de la KB de Microsoft explican en detalle como hacerlo y el código que tendrías sería mas o memos así (*código obtenido de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258678) de SO en Ingles*):

```
//Most of this code was from David Hayden's blog:
// http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\TestSO1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;""";
    DbProviderFactory factory =
      DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();  //open the connection

            //use the '$' notation after the sheet name to indicate that this is
            // an existing sheet and not to actually create it.  This basically defines
            // the metadata for the insert statements that will follow.
            // If the '$' notation is removed, then a new sheet is created named 'Sheet1'.
            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet1$] (F1 number, F2 char(255), F3 char(128))";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //now we insert the values into the existing sheet...no new sheet is added.
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2, F3) VALUES(4,\"Tampa\",\"Florida\")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //insert another row into the sheet...
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2, F3) VALUES(5,\"Pittsburgh\",\"Pennsylvania\")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Por cierto, también existe una librería llamada [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) que permite trabajar con archivos en ambos formatos aunque, para trabajar con el nuevo formato `XLSX`, te recomiendo cualquiera de las dos anteriores porque, por lo que recuerdo, son mas eficientes.

Answer (score 0):

Mi opción preferida y la más sencilla de todas, es utilizar una librería llamada [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Esta librería se encarga de generar archivos nativos de Excel y no simplemente de maquilar un documento HTML cambiándole la extensión a XLS para que Excel lo intente abrir, que es lo que tú estás haciendo y la razón por la cual Excel saca ese aviso de advertencia. Con EPPLus el código sería así:

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreDelArchivo + "");
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Nombre de la hoja");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  pck.SaveAs(ms);
  ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  
}
```